# Bash: adding a key/value pair to an existing config file

Tags: bash, config

I have an existing config `config.ini` file with the following content:

```
VALUE_A=a
VALUE_B=b
```

Using Bash, I'd like to add a new key-value pair `VALUE_C=c` to get the following:

```
VALUE_A=a
VALUE_B=b
VALUE_C=c
```

Is there a concise way to do this with Bash (ideally a one liner)?

Comment: `echo VALUE_C=c >> config.ini`?

Comment: oh yeah, easier than I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the answer is simply:

`echo VALUE_C=c >> config.ini`